# generate SER certificate files

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I am reading through the source code of [indianwebproxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indiawebproxy/) and it uses **proxycertificate.ser** file for the certificate when using ssl.
The problem is that this certificate is expired and i want to generate my own so that i could test it on real servers in firefox.
Can you guys guide me on generating java certificate files with the .ser extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.ser` extension probably just means it is a [Java serialized object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). The [X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) class does in fact implement Serializable.

My guess is that you just need to serialize your X509Certificate instance.

Comment: +1 I think you are right, but it would be rather stupid to serialize the certificate to disk. Normally you would simply use the ASN.1 DER encoding, which is compatible with any language and does not change over versions.

Comment: @owlstead: Right, java has no problem creating an X509 certificate from the standard, language-independent DER encoding. Perhaps the developers of IndianWebProxy are not familiar with encryption software and standards.